# Prevent duplication of contact record phone using map with apex trigger

Tags: apex, before-trigger

**My Implementation:**

trigger contactTrigger on Contact (before insert) {

```
Switch on Trigger.OperationType
{
    when BEFORE_INSERT
    {
        contactHandler.checkDup(Trigger.new);
        
    }
    
    
}
```

}

**Handler class:**

public class ContactHandler {

```
public static void checkDup(List<Contact> conList) {
    Map<String, Integer> phoneCountMap = new Map<String, Integer>();

    // Populate phoneCountMap with the count of each phone number.
    for (Contact c : conList) {
        String phoneNumber = c.Phone;
        if (phoneCountMap.containsKey(phoneNumber)) {
            phoneCountMap.put(phoneNumber, phoneCountMap.get(phoneNumber) + 1);
        } else {
            phoneCountMap.put(phoneNumber, 1);
        }
    }

    // Identify duplicate phone numbers and add error messages accordingly.
    Set<String> duplicatePhoneNumbers = new Set<String>();
    for (String phone : phoneCountMap.keySet()) {
        if (phoneCountMap.get(phone) > 1) {
            duplicatePhoneNumbers.add(phone);
        }
    }

    // Add error messages for duplicate phone numbers.
    for (Contact c : conList) {
        if (duplicatePhoneNumbers.contains(c.Phone)) {
            c.Phone.addError('You have a duplicate contact with phone number: ' + c.Phone);
        }
    }
}
```

}

While i'm testing the code,duplicate records keep on adding so where I'm making mistake and what is the workaround to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are not matching the phone numbers with existing contact phonenumber in the database. You are just doing it with records in trigger context. Hence it allowing you to insert.

There are several example available on google for similar requirement:-

1. https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54V00007T4IfrSAF
2. https://www.pantherschools.com/how-to-prevent-duplicate-record-using-trigger/
3. https://www.syedtaha.com/salesforce-apex-triggers/salesforce-apex-trigger-to-prevent-duplicate-contacts-by-email-or-phone-number/897/

attaching a sample code for email duplicate check from [here](https://www.sfdc-lightning.com/2022/10/apex-trigger-to-avoid-duplicate-contact.html):-

```
public void methodToHandleBeforeInsert(List<Contact> newConList) {
   Set<string> emailOfIncomingContacts = new Set<String>();
   // Storing incoming contact email in set of string
   Set<string> existingConCheckFromDatabaseWithIncomingEmail = new Set<string>();
   for(Contact con:newConList){
      emailOfIncomingContacts.add(con.email);
   }
   // Querying contact from database to check if any contact exist with incoming email
   for(Contact con2:[SELECT id,email from Contact where email in:emailOfIncomingContacts]){
      existingConCheckFromDatabaseWithIncomingEmail.add(con2.email);
   }
   // Preventing duplicate contact from getting inserted in database.
   for(Contact con3:newConList){
      if(existingConCheckFromDatabaseWithIncomingEmail.contains(con3.email)){
      con3.addError('Contact already exists in database with email'+con3.email);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the ways to do it. I have used the set here to store unique phone values and if any new contact has the phone value which is already present in the set, it will throw an error.

```
 public static void checkDup(List<Contact> conList){
    Set<String>phone = new Set<String>(); // to store unique values of phone
    List<Contact>oldContacts = [Select Id, Phone from Contact]; // list of old contacts so that we can loop and add their phone no. in set
for(Contact oldC : oldContacts){
    if(oldC.Phone != null){
    phone.add(oldC.Phone);
  }
}
for(Contact c : conList){
    if(phone.contains(c.Phone)){
    c.Phone.addError('You have a duplicate contact with phone number: ' + c.Phone);
    }
    phone.add(c.Phone);
}
```

}